# SQL Query to get the total sales per seller by month

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try this:

```
SELECT
  profile.user_id,
  profile.name,
  total_month.total as month10
FROM profile
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
      order.seller_id,
      COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM order
    WHERE MONTH(order.data_hora) = 10
    GROUP BY order.seller_id) AS total_month
    ON total_month.seller_id= profile.user_id;
```

The result was this:

```
-------------------------
|user_id| name  |month10|
-------------------------
|   5   |user1  |  73   |
|   1   |user2  |   1   |
-------------------------
```

But I need more months like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| user_id | name  | month10 | month11 | month12 |
-------------------------------------------------
|    5    | user1 |   73    |    52   |    65   |
|    1    | user2 |   67    |    56   |    78   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

How could I do this without creating a function?

Comment: I think you need to join with a table with 12 months,simple ints.

Comment: Search for **mysql rows to columns** or **mysql pivot**

Comment: I'm not sure if MySQL allows it, but you should research "PIVOT".. Might be your answer

Comment: try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740616/how-to-turn-rows-into-columns

Comment: as @Schalk said you need a `pivot table` which is, in my point of view a pain in the.... to do in mysql. As you have 12 moths would be enough for you if your query bring the data with all months ? even if there is no value ?

Comment: Yes @JorgeCampos, I have 12 months, but it will be flexible and sometime I can use 12 months and another time only 3. I want to get the values​​, even empty or null.

Comment: I asked because I can create a query that can give you a table with the 12 months (wont be flexible) for the months that doesnt have value  it will show 0 as value. If it fits to let me know. Otherwise you will have to create a function with for a pivot table

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your query to do what you want.  Just be more flexible in the subquery:

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.name,
       tm.month10, tm.month11, tm.month12
FROM profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT o.seller_id,
             sum(o.data_hora = 10) as month10,
             sum(o.data_hora = 11) as month11,
             sum(o.data_hora = 12) as month12
      FROM order o
      WHERE MONTH(order.data_hora) in (10, 11, 12)
      GROUP BY order.seller_id
     ) tm
     ON tm.seller_id = p.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, it was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Well as I said in the comments supporting the @Schalk comment, in order to get this working as you want you will need a function to get a `DYNAMIC PIVOT TABLE` or `TRANSPOSE ROWS TO COLUMNS` google it if you prefer.

For your solution I've created a query that gives you all months/values like this:

```
user_id  name  jan feb mar  apr  may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
   1       a    0   0   1   10    0   0   1   2   7   2   3   0 
   2       b    1   0   0    0    2   0   0   0   3   1   1   0
```

If it fits to your problem this is your query:

```
select
    profile.user_id,
    profile.name,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 1, 1, 0 )) as Jan,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 2, 1, 0 )) as Feb,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 3, 1, 0 )) as Mar,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 4, 1, 0 )) as Apr,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 5, 1, 0 )) as May,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 6, 1, 0 )) as Jun,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 7, 1, 0 )) as Jul,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 8, 1, 0 )) as Aug,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 9, 1, 0 )) as Sep,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 10, 1, 0 )) as Oct,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 11, 1, 0 )) as Nov,
    sum(if( MONTH(orderr.data_hora) = 12, 1, 0 )) as Dece
from 
    profile left join orderr 
                   on profile.user_id = orderr.seller_id
group by profile.user_id,
         profile.name
```

I've created a fiddle to it (but the `data_hora` column I created as integer to make it quickly to do it, it is for understanding).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a1a2e/5

Comment: Thank you also @JorgeCampos already gave me to understand that there is different solutions to do this!

Answer (score 0):

It was perfect!

The field type 'data_hora' is datetime, so I made a small change.

```
SELECT p.user_id,
       p.name,
       tm.month10,
       tm.month11,
       tm.month12,
       (tm.month10+tm.month11+tm.month12) AS final_total
FROM profile p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT o.seller_id,
          sum(month(o.data_hora) = 10) AS month10,
          sum(month(o.data_hora) = 11) AS month11,
          sum(month(o.data_hora) = 12) AS month12
   FROM order o
   WHERE MONTH(ORDER.data_hora) IN (10, 11, 12)
   GROUP BY ORDER.seller_id ) tm 
   ON tm.seller_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY final_total DESC;
```

How could I optimize the field "final_total"?